# Error in ST1S41PHR LED Driver circuit diagram? "Unfinished Nets"

Tags: led, buck, driver, st, easyeda

I am just starting trying to design simple circuits (using EasyEDA), and I have an issue with an "Unfinished Net", in this 12Vdc_in, 9Vdc_out, 2.5A Buck Driver circuit.

From the both the ST Microelectronics datasheet and eDesign Studio snip, it shows Vin_A tied in between Cin_A and Vin_SW.

- After some research, I am embarrassed to admit that I still do not know why Vin_A and
  V-n_SW are joined
- EasyEDA warns that "More than one Netlabel is found in wire, please check if this is
  correct, if yes, ignore this message". The EasyEDA Netlabels in question are highlighted
  in RED.

Can anyone please advise on the function of this portion of the circuit and why ST Micro configures the circuit in this way?

[image: ST1S41PHR Datasheet Circuit]

[image: ST eDesign Studio Circuit]

[image: My EasyEDA Circuit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used that program, but the answer is universal.

You can't have two net labels, Vin and VinA, on same net (wire), because which name would that wire have if it has two labels that try to name it.

Choose one name and use it.

Since those wires carry a single VCC supply to both Vin and VinA pins on a chip, why not just have a single label like VCC and draw VCC to both chip pins.

If you ask why the pins are joined, the chip just has two supply voltage input pins, there is a diagram of chip internals in the data sheet.

Sometimes chips have multiple supply and ground pins for some reason, like if one set can't carry enough current.

But on this case one pin is used for powering the chip internals and the other pin is the supply current pin for the power to be switched.

And they are drawn in a way how the actual connections should be made on a PCB to make sure currents flow through the PCB wires in a way that makes sense so that for example the feedback measures the output voltage at some specific point like the capacitor, instead of measuring the output at the chip if the capacitor is further away with large currents causing voltage drops in the wiring.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that they are both just voltage input pins! I had assumed they performed completely separate functions because VinA is called "unregulated voltage input" in the data sheet. I standardized all of the Netlabels as you suggested and the program is happy now. Thanks for helping the newb learn!

Comment: Just don't burn your LEDs. If those are standard LEDs, driving them directly from a voltage source makes little sense.

Comment: They are Cree XP-L emitters. 2.95Vf and rated for 3A max. Plus they will be heavily heatsinked. I hope they hold up!